# change the line color in normal state of MaterialBetterSpinner

Tags: android, styles, material-design

How can i change the color of line in `com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner`
in android when its normal state, i already use `app:met_primaryColor="#f00"` but it only work when spinner is focus.

Answer (score -1):

Use `app:backgroundTint="@color/buttonGrey"` for normal state.